# Having more than one facebook login connector on B2C Azure login?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Azure AD B2C let you set up just one Facebook login. But what happens when you want to connect to the same b2c directory more than one web app. Facebook forces you to insert logo and policy.

If I have two web apps, I would need to have the chance to setup 2 different facebook logins with different policy and logo. I can do on facebook developer, but seems azure b2c supports just one.

is there a way to achieve that? Maybe using open id account?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the details where the facebook forcing you to insert logo and policy. Based on the configuration [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-facebook) there is no where it request you to configure the logo and policy. Please share the document details which you are refering

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add it as a custom OIDC provider. Or otherwise use custom policies where you can define as many as you like.